# Opengl ES glGetAttribLocation problem! 0x0502 error

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, runtime-error, glsl

There is a error when glGetAttribLocation excuted. And I don't know why it is.
I tried to check program things, shaders, and logics. But I couldn't resolve this problem...
I think there was a problem happend when creating program or passed program. But I don't know where the problem is..
Below is the execution log and codes.

**Log**

```
Shader has loaded : 1, 2
D/Debug: Program has linked
E/Error: vPosition attribute: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 401
    Process: com.sholgames.projd, PID: 11352
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find value 'vPosition'.
        at com.sholgames.projd.CModel.<init>(CModel.java:114)
        at com.sholgames.projd.CGLRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(CGLRenderer.java:18)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1539)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f76b320: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xefaf4a40)
Process 11352 terminated.
```

**CModel.java**

```
public CModel(float[] verticeCoords_, short[] drawOrder_, float[] color_, int vertexShaderId_, int fragmentShaderId_) {
    LogManager.LOG_DEBUG_MESSAGE("Start creating model class");

    //Input factor data to member variable
    mVertexCoords = verticeCoords_;
    mDrawOrder = drawOrder_;
    mColor = color_;

    //Shader Load
    mVertexShader = IOManager.LoadShaderCode(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderId_);
    mFragmentShader = IOManager.LoadShaderCode(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderId_);
    LogManager.LOG_DEBUG_MESSAGE("Shader has loaded : " + mVertexShader + ", " + mFragmentShader);

    //Create program
    mProgramObject = glCreateProgram();

    //Attach shader
    glAttachShader(mProgramObject, mVertexShader);
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("Attach vertex shader");
    glAttachShader(mProgramObject, mFragmentShader);
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("Attach fragment shader");

    //Bind shader
    glBindAttribLocation(mProgramObject, 0, "vPosition");
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("Bind position attrib");
    glBindAttribLocation(mProgramObject, 1, "vColor");
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("Bind color attrib");

    //Link program
    glLinkProgram(mProgramObject);
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("Linking program");
    LogManager.LOG_DEBUG_MESSAGE("Program has linked");
    int[] result = new int[1];
    glGetProgramiv(mProgramObject, GL_LINK_STATUS, result, 0);
    if(result[0] == -1) throw new RuntimeException("ERROR : shader program link failed.");

    //active data
    glUseProgram(mProgramObject);
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("Check using program");
    LogManager.LOG_DEBUG_MESSAGE("Program has actived");

    //Generate buffer id
    mBuffersID = new int[10];

    //Vertex buffer
    mVertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVertexCoords.length * 4)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mVertexBuffer.put(mVertexCoords);
    mVertexBuffer.position(0);

    //Draw order buffer
    mDrawOrderBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mDrawOrder.length * 2)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
    mDrawOrderBuffer.put(mDrawOrder);
    mDrawOrderBuffer.position(0);

    //Color Buffer
    mColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mColor.length * 4)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mColorBuffer.put(mColor);
    mColorBuffer.position(0);

    //VBO
    glGenBuffers(3, mBuffersID, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffersID[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexCoords.length, mVertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffersID[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mColor.length, mColorBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //EBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffersID[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mDrawOrder.length, mDrawOrderBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //VAO
    int[] vaoIDs = new int[1];
    glGenVertexArrays(1, vaoIDs, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoIDs[0]);

    //Pointing vertex attribute
    int vertexCoordAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "vPosition");
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("vPosition attribute");
    if(vertexCoordAttrib == -1) throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find value 'vPosition'.");
    int colorAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "vColor");
    LogManager.CHECK_ERROR("vColor attribute");
    if(colorAttrib == -1) throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find value 'vColor'.");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffersID[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexCoordAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexCoordAttrib);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffersID[1]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttrib, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttrib);

    LogManager.LOG_DEBUG_MESSAGE("Create model class done");
}
```

**vertexshader.glsl**

```
#version 300 es
attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 vPassColor;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    vPassColor = vColor;
}
```

**fragmentshader.glsl**

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 vPassColor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vPassColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shaders do not compile. The keywords `attribute` and `varying` such as the built in fragment shader output `gl_FragColor` are deprecated in [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf).

Use the keywords `in`, `out` and specify an `out` variable for the fragment shader output:

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 300 es

in  vec3 vPosition;
in  vec4 vColor;
out vec4 vPassColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    vPassColor  = vColor;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in  vec4 vPassColor;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = vPassColor;
}
```

---

Note, it is still possible to use a [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf)  shader in OpenGL ES 3.0. (In that case the version directive has to be still `#version 100 es`)

---

I recommend to use `glGetShaderi`/`glGetShaderInfoLog` to retrieve shader compile errors. See [Java Code Examples for `glGetShaderInfoLog()`](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20&method=glGetShaderInfoLog).
Use `glGetProgramiv`/`glGetProgramInfoLog` to retrieve link errors. See [Java Code Examples for `glGetProgramInfoLog()`](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.opengl.GLES20&method=glGetProgramInfoLog).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did what you wrote down. And then I found a new log message. It is as follows :

`Fragment info
----------
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting "::" at token ","
0(1) : error C0160: invalid character literal`